# Como centralizar uma div com tamanho variável e position absolute?

Tags: html, css, front-end

Tenho uma dúvida que está me consumindo muito tempo, seguinte:

Preciso centralizar o contador da imagem abaixo, porém ele precisa ficar no rodapé da tela (com `position:absolute`) e a `div` dele tem tamanho variável.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a minha `div` tivesse um tamanho fixo, poderia usar tranquilamente `margin:0 auto;`

Porém alem de ser variável, está com `position:absolute;` e com `bottom:0;`, segue código completo:

```
#clock{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Vejam como tá ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Oi Fernando, o que significa tamanho variável?

Comment: Precisa mesmo ser div? De vez em quando vale a pena apelar pra uma table (ou "display:table") pra esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Variável é porque ela não tem uma largura definida, vai depender dos números e da resolução da tela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não indicaste a tua markup para obteres uma solução perfeitamente adequada ao teu caso, mas fica uma solução sem recorrer a declarações de CSS que possam por em causa a apresentação da página devido ao uso de navegadores mais antigos:

1. O elemento que serve de *wrapper* vai ser posicionado no fundo da página, com uma largura de 100% da tela.
2. Os elementos do relógio vão ficar `inline-block` para que possamos alinhar os mesmos ao centro sem perder a possibilidade de os formatar como pretendido.

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/eL1eacuw/).

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px;
  color: skyblue;
}

/* para a demonstração */
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; font-size: 14px; background-color: black; width:100%; }
ul { margin:0; padding:0; }
li > small { font-size: 0.6em; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>129<br/><small>dias</small></li>
  <li>09<br/><small>horas</small></li>
  <li>39<br/><small>minutos</small></li>
  <li>11<br/><small>segundos</small></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfeito @Zull

Analisando sua resposta, pude perceber que estava faltando o width:100% no elemento pai (tag header) e no wrapper.

Adicionalmente tive que colocar um left:0; na ul, não entendi muito bem o motivo, pois usando sua implementação ele jogou para a direita, mas agora funcionou perfeitamente, inclusive em resoluções menores.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Variável como? Responsivo? Você está ou deveria estar usando um "container" no conteúdo todo para centralizar as informações.
Caso esteja usando o container e o site seja responsivo, defina um valor de width para esse container respeitando os breakpoints que vc deseja usando media queries.
Agora, se você quiser que fique centralizado o conteudo de dentro tendo 3 ou menos boxes, sugiro você utilizar um pouco de javascript/jquery divindo 100% pelo numero de elementos e aplicando o resultado como o novo width de cada box.
Ou caso você não se preocupe com IE8 pra baixo, pode dar uma lida sobre flex-box CSS3.

Comment: Exato, por causa do responsivo.
Queria evitar um pouco javascript, mas talvez seja uma opção também.

Experimentei o flex-box mas no meu caso ele aumentava o tamanho dos box também, então acabei desistindo dele.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso resolve:

```
#clock{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;

 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, acredito muito por causa do position absolute.

Comment: se a largura fosse fixa daria para centralizar.

Comment: Sim, se você observar o logo, ele está com largura fixa, então centralizei sem problemas, a dificuldade nesse caso é justamente essa, não posso definir uma largura fixa :(

Comment: Da para fazer o seguinte: #clock{left: 50%; margin-left: -Xpx} Sendo X a largura média do elemento dividida por 2. Não ia ficar perfeito, mas em conjunto com a solução do natan ia quebrar um galho nos navegadores antigos.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode user o transform: translate(-50%, -50%); left: 50%; position: absolute; quando não possui o tamanho do elemento.

Neste link tem várias formas de fazer a centralização:
http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/centralizando-com-css-um-guia-completo.php